# Heaviside Step Function with a function in the argument

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

For simple Heaviside functions we see that $H(x - 1)$ describes $$H(x - 1) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x > 1 \\ 
0 & x < 1
\end{array}\right. \hspace{5ex}$$

So for a function of $H(\pi^2 - 4x^2)$ would you have to set the argument equal to zero and find x as before and get:$$H(\pi^2 - 4x^2) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x > \pi /2 \\ 
0 & x < \pi /2
\end{array}\right. \hspace{5ex}?$$

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great!

Comment: I don't understand $$H(-x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x > 1 \\ 
0 & x < 1
\end{array}\right. \hspace{5ex}$$. For me: $$H(-x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x < 0 \\ 
0 & x > 0
\end{array}\right. \hspace{5ex}...$$

Answer (score 2):

Besides, the two different cases in the second equation are exact.

One can consider $H(f(x))$ as the characteristic function of the set

$$F = \{x \ | \ f(x)>0 \}$$

**Therefore $H(-f(x))$ is the characteristic function of the complementary set $\overline{F}.$**

In the same vein : $H(f(x)).H(g(x))$ is the characteristic function of the intersection of two sets, etc.

Comment: So is this correct?  $$H(f(x)) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & f(x) > 1 \\  0 & f(x) < 1 \end{array}\right. \hspace{5ex}$$  Is there a good web (or other) source for the properties of the Heaviside step?